# Pull jars to libs folder from other directory before building the Android application

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project, that is dependant on an external jar file, i.e. `A.jar`.

I have configured my android `build.gradle` to first build the project that builds `A.jar`. Then the Android build proceeds.

What is the best way to copy the jar from its build folder into the android projects lib folder, after the jar builds?

So the build should proceed as...

> Build Jar > Copy Jar to Libs > Build Android Project.

I don't use Android Studio, so I configure my project only through gradle config file manipulation.

The project that currently builds the jar is already listed as a dependency in `app/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "saf.mobilebeats2"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation project(':dawcore')
    // runtime files('../DawCore/build/libs/DawCore.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not using Android Studio and the dependency module is located in some other place where it is being used by some other projects, you might consider having the jar copied in your `libs` directory after the dependency module finishes the build and creates the jar to be copied. So the overall execution is as follows:

- Task 1. Build the dependency module
- Task 2. Copy the jar file to a specific location to be used by your android application.
- Task 3. While building your Android application, copy the jar file from that specific location to your `libs` directory.
- Task 4. Build the jar using `compile files('libs/jar-from-dependency.jar')`

Now for Task 1 & 2: add the following in the `build.gradle` file of your dependency module. Hence after building the dependency module, this will copy the jar to a location specified in the copy task. Check the copy function below to get an idea on how to write a copy function in gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task finalize << {
    println('Here use the copyTask to copy the jar to a specific directory after each build of your library module')
}

build.finalizedBy(finalize)
// compileJava.finalizedBy(copyJarToAndroid) <-- In your case
```

Here is the [doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#finalizedBy(java.lang.Object...)) for necessary functions related to this.

For Task 3: Now the task is simple. You need to copy the jar from that specific location into your Android application project before building with gradle. Here's how you can initiate a copy task before building your project.

```
task copyFiles(type: Copy) {
    description = 'Copying the jar'
    from 'your/jar/directory'
    into project(':Path:To:ModuleFrom:Settings.gradle').file('./libs')
    include 'jar-from-dependency.jar'
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    preBuild.dependsOn copyFiles
}

clean.dependsOn copyFiles
clean.mustRunAfter copyFiles
```

This will run the `copyFiles` task when the gradle clean is initiated.

Hence for Task 4: Add the jar in your `dependencies` section.

```
dependencies {
    // ... Other dependencies
    compile files('libs/jar-from-dependency.jar')
}
```

Comment: The other gradle project that builds the jar is separate from the android project, and other java projects use it, I dont think it would be suiting to put it in the android project directory.

Comment: I see. Let me update the answer so that it fits your requirement.

Comment: The project build proceeds as Build Jar > copy jar > Build Android. Currently called task assemble on the android build first builds the jar. So won't the solution you provided with the copyTask proceed as Copy Jar > Build Jar > Build Android?

Comment: Yes, `Copy Jar > Build Jar > Build Android` this is somewhat I thought of.

Comment: I require jar to build before the copy, as I could be updating code in that project as well.

Comment: I see! I have updated the first part of my answer and hope that helps you. Good luck!

Comment: Could you update the answer to be more concise, with all examples focused on the final solution of having the lib gradle build move the jar to the android libs directory on its own. Since this is the only viable solution, no point having the additional stuff.

Comment: Sure thing! I am doing it. I am just keeping the portion which directly answers this question. Thanks.

Comment: Just to note, the android gradle build called compileJava on the jars gradle project, so the finalize task must be set as compileJava.finalizedBy(copyJarToAndroid)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I am editing my answer and will get back to you here shortly. Check and verify for me then!

Comment: Can you please check the answer now?

Comment: For Task 3 where do I put this in the gradle file?

Comment: @JPM you can put it before the dependencies. The idea is to chain the functions together using `clean.dependsOn`. So that the task will run before the `clean` task.

Comment: Yeah I have another project where we build the two aars and then depending on the build of the App we want to pull in either the debug aar or the release aar.

Answer (score 0):

the most easy might be to remove the direct module dependency:

```
// implementation project(':dawcore')
```

a) and set up a local `flatDir` repository, which Android Studio will list as a "Library Repository":

```
repositories {
    flatDir { dirs "/home/user/project/dawcore/build/outputs/aar" }
}
```

then one can depend on the artifacts of the library module:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.acme.dawcore:dawcore-debug:1.0.0@aar"
    // implementation "com.acme.dawcore:dawcore-release:1.0.0@aar"
}
```

b) or set up the `libs` directory as `flatDir`:

```
repositories {
    flatDir { dirs "libs" }
}
```

and add a `Copy` task to the library's `build.gradle`:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleDebug' || task.name == 'assembleRelease') {
        task.finalizedBy copyArtifacts
    }
}

// dawcore:copyArtifacts
task copyArtifacts(type: Copy) {
    from("$buildDir/outputs/aar") {
        include "*.aar"
    }
    from("$buildDir/outputs/jar") {
        include "*.jar"
    }
    into file("${rootProject.projectDir}/mobile/libs")
    doLast {
        def path = ant.path {
            fileset(dir: "${rootProject.projectDir}/mobile/libs", includes: "*.aar, *.jar")
        }
        path.list().each {
            println it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does that value provided to "implementation" represent exactly?

Comment: @ScottF the build artifact of the library project. for `AAR` one needs `flatDir`, while `JAR` can be copied. the problem is that there are no "Move", but only `Copy` & `Delete` tasks.

Comment: Sorry I am still confused :s. What specifically does the string literal in the field 'flatDir' and the string literal in the field 'implementation' represent.

Comment: @ScottF the `flatDir` is the location of a local `AAR` repository, where private dependencies are being expected. that string is: group (the package name), module (the file name), version (library version), `@` library package format.