# Android imported library in module is not reflecting in app module

Tags: android, gradle

I've made 'ModuleA' and exported it as '.aar' file.

I've a 'ModuleB, included '.aar' file of 'ModuleA' as :

`api (name:'ModuleA', ext:'aar')`

In 'ModuleB' my class is inheriting class of 'ModuleA'.

Now when I use 'ModuleB' in my 'app' module as :
 `implementation project(path: ':ModuleB')`

it says unable to resolve 'ModuleA'

Comment: The answer which I've once left [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621869/pull-jars-to-libs-folder-from-other-directory-before-building-the-android-applic) should explain the problematic which you are facing. In short, you'd need to supply the AAR dependency with a `flatDir` repository.

Comment: Sorry, but I wouldn't reopen that unless the relevant `build.gradle` had been provided; it is unclear if the AAR can even be resolved for (as suggested above). Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), because this question is currently too abstract to reproduce it easily (theory vs. practice). I could also have closed it for "needs debug information"; linking a seemingly duplicate is still more helpful then no suggestion at all.